# php/gd can't remove background after creating a circular image

Tags: php, gd, photo, transparent

I'm using a script to make a photo circular with a transparent background then positioning it on another image. When adding it, the pink background color that was removed reappears but when I open the circle image in the browser there is no pink background color. It's transparent.

```
  $img1 = imagecreatefromjpeg("/path/uploads/resized-".$_POST["photo"]);

  $x=imagesx($img1)-$width ;
  $y=imagesy($img1)-$height;
  $img2 = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);
  $bg = imagecolorallocate($img2, 255, 200, 255);
  imagefill($img2, 0, 0, $bg);
  $e = imagecolorallocate($img2, 0, 0, 0);
  $r = $x <= $y ? $x : $y;

  imagefilledellipse($img2, ($x/2), ($y/2), $r, $r, $e); 
  imagecolortransparent($img2, $e);
  imagecopymerge($img1, $img2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y, 100);
  imagecolortransparent($img1, $bg);

  $tempimageround = str_replace('.jpg','','/path/uploads/circle-'.$_POST["photo"]).'.png';

  imagepng($img1,$tempimageround);  
  $new_photo2 = imagecreatefrompng($tempimageround);

imagecopy($jpg_image, $new_photo2, $photoleft, $phototop, 0, 0,$photowidth, $photoheight);
imagedestroy($img2);
imagedestroy($img1);
```

/path/uploads/circle-photo.png has the transparent background when viewed in the browser but retains the background color of 255,200,255 when placed on top of $jpg_image. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: tagged `Eclipse` - do not spam with irrelevant tags! Do you really though this is tag about drawing eclipses with 100K followers? :)

Comment: ...are you saying don't use eclipse as a tag because it's irrelevant - even though the script uses the gd eclipse function? Not quite following you...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse and read tag description